# how to remove dt tag in zend form for a particular field

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to remove the `dt` tag in zend form for only one field. Please let me know how can I do that. Here is the code that I am trying and not getting the `dt` tag removed:

```
$day = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('day','day');
$day->setLabel('')
    ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
    ->setOptions(array('class' => 'width100'))
    ->addMultiOptions(array('Select Type' => '',))
    ->addMultiOptions($day_of_month);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug use : `Zend_Debug::dump(get_class_methods($day));` , we now have a list of methods we can use, the one that would help us in this case would be `getDecorators()`, so : `Zend_Debug::dump($day->getDecorators());`

We will see that `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label` has the tag `dt` witch you whant to remove.

Given the name of the decorator we can do : `$day->removeDecorator('Label');` and see the dt decorator has left the building .

Comment: when I echoed Zend_Debug::dump($day->getDecorators()); I got the following, plz let me know what I can do next to remove the dt tag : ["Zend_Form_Decorator_Label"] => object(Zend_Form_Decorator_Label)#438 (5) {
    ["_placement":protected] => string(7) "PREPEND"
    ["_tag":protected] => NULL
    ["_element":protected] => NULL
    ["_options":protected] => array(1) {
      ["tag"] => string(2) "dt"
    }
    ["_separator":protected] => string(2) "
"

Comment: $day->removeDecorator('Label'); and see the dt decorator has left the building .

Comment: but what if I want to remove the "dt" and keep the label?

Comment: @darksoulsong it's been a while since i've played with zend, i remember that you can register you're own decorator so i suggest looking into that